# On **'Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo'** microphone, no device detected for sound input!

Tags: sound, microphone

I realized that my new office computer (Ubuntu 18.04, the reason for mentioning 'office computer' is that I didn't do the setup myself, was just handed it over) is not allowing input volume. While going to google meet, online mic testing, I found that this device has **'Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo'** microphone but it was unable to capture any input sound. So I thought it might be muted and hence, went to Settings and **in the slot of input sound, there was no device to be chosen** as in the following picture:

[image]

How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: To be clear the monitor has a built in mic? How does the monitor and the mic connect to the computer?

Comment: @David Honestly I don't know very clearly. In fact I found output audio only coming from the jack/port for headphone on the CPU.

Comment: Personally I have not seen monitors with mic in, speakers yea I am pretty sure the mic needs to be plugged into the computer. I think you are misreading monitor I do not think it is referring to the video device. But the ability to monitor sound from the computer jacks.

Comment: @David I mentioned the exact terminology which I found while online mic testing

Comment: OK I will try one more time, Do you have a mic? Where it it plugged into? Does the computer have more then 1 jack you can plug a mic into? Have you tired them all if it does? Have you tried the mic on another computer or with a different OS?